# Count variable in Python function

Tags: python, variables

```
def prime_numbers(number_list):
        prime_list = []`
        for number in number_list:
            count = 0
            for prime in range(1, number):
                if number % prime == 0:
                    count += 1
            if count == 1:
                prime_list.append(number)


        print(prime_list)

prime_numbers([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 11, 13, 21, 19])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Count here is used as a flag.

when it gets to 1, it means that the number is divisible by another number and hence not a prime